# Display the first row of view data in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a a ViewData with 8 rows. The ForEach loop works fine, but I need to extract the very first row before the foreach.

I need to extract only the first row to inject the default video in the iframe.

```
<iframe name="myFrame" width="800" height="500" src="@item.ID?wmode=transparent" allowfullscreen="True"></iframe>
```

Here is the foreach that works 100%

---

```
@foreach (var item in (List<VideoModel>)ViewData["Videos"])
{
  <tr class="sep">
    <td>@item.DisplayNumber</td>
    <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Play Video", "IframeRedirect", "Home", new { ContentID = item.ID }, new { target = "someFrame", @class = "cbutton" })
    </td>
    <td>@item.Time @item.Hd</td>
    <td><b>@item.Title</b><br />@item.Description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><b>Author:</b> @item.Author <br /><a href="@item.AuthorSubscriptionUrl" target="@item.AuthorSubscriptionUrl">Subscribe to youtube channel</a></td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: `@foreach (var item in (List<VideoModel>)ViewData["Videos"])`?? Pass the collection to your view using a strongly typed model! `@model List<VideoModel>` and `@foreach(var item in Model) {`. To access the first item `Model[0]`

Comment: You are looking at the view code.
Is there a shorter way to display the first row without having to use @foreach model[0]?

Comment: It's not `foreach  model[0]` (you don't need a loop to get the first item). If your model is `List<VideoModel>` then `Model[0]` returns the first item in the collection (so `Model[0].ID` returns the value of the ID property of the first `VideoModel` in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the first row like following:

```
var firstRow = ((List<VideoModel>)ViewData["Videos"]).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model is a IEnumerable
You can get the first like following:

```
var first = Model.First();
```